# System of nonlinear equations with Banach fixed-point theorem

Tags: numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, banach-fixed-point

How do i show that this system of nonlinear equations can be solved on $D:=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2 :  |x|,|y| \leq \frac{1}{2} $}
$$\frac{1}{2}x^2-x- \frac{1}{2}y^2+\frac{3}{8}$$
$$\frac{1}{2}x^2-y+ \frac{1}{2}y^2-\frac{1}{2}$$

I was thinking on using Banach fixed-point theorem but im not really sure on how to deal with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference of both equations,
$$
0=-x+y+\frac38-\frac12 = y-x-\frac18
$$
allows you to eliminate one variable and reduce the problem to a univariate quadratic equation.

---

See [the problem on WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2-2x-y%5E2%2B3%2F4%3D0,+x%5E2-2y-y%5E2%2B1%3D0) for a quick confirmation of the result. You will see that one of the solutions is at infinity, that is, the substitution eliminates all quadratic terms.

Comment: Thank you. I just realized i made a mistakes in the equations and edited it. I tried to use your trick and i got $$0 = -y^2 -x +y + \frac{7}{8}$$

Then I put the $x$ on the left handed site and defined a function $F(y) = -y^2 +y +\frac{7}{8}$ and calculated the zeroes. Is this the correct way?

Comment: I think i only have to show the 3 requirements of the Banach fixed-point theorem with $$F(x,y)= \begin{pmatrix}x^2 -2x -y^2 +\frac{3}{4}\\ x^2-2y+y^2-1\end{pmatrix}$$ If those are shown it follows that both equations have a unique fixed point in $D$. 

Though I am failing to show $F(D) \subseteq D$...

Comment: No, if you insert $x=-y^2+y+\frac78$ into the first equation, you get a 4th degree polynomial equation as one can expect for the intersection of an hyperbolic curve with a circle. There are only 2 real solutions, one close to $(x,y)=(0.38,-0.36)$.

Comment: wow im so stupid i didnt even think about inserting it into the first equation.... Thank you ill try that

Comment: In principle yes, but you will first need to bring your equations into fixed-point form, like $x_+=\frac12(x^2-y^2)+\frac38$, $y_+=\frac12(x^2+y^2)-\frac12$.

Comment: got it thank you alot!